# "Помогаем, чем можем". Верны ли здесь знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

*Потихоньку помогаем, чем можем, маленьким инвалидам-сиротам в интернатах.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё верно: *Потихоньку помогаем, чем можем, маленьким инвалидам-сиротам в интернатах.*

...*чем можем* - неполное придаточное предложение внутри главного(чем можем помочь), оно отделяется запятыми.

Answer (score 0):

Грамота утверждает, что это устойчивое выражение, поэтому запятая не нужна.

**Угощала чем могла.** (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286506)
**На первых порах нам помогали чем могли.** (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286039)
**Мы всегда чем могли помогали им.** (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=240300)
**Помогали чем могли.** (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=266931)
**Помогите чем можете.** (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=277674)

Но: **И всегда, чем мог, он помогал**. (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=258505)